# SQL Server Driver for PHP sqlsrv_connect() Filling PHP Error Log with Ignored Errors

Tags: php, sql-server, logging, error-handling

Every time my PHP application connects to my SQL Server database, the following gets put into the PHP error log:

```
[01-Apr-2011 12:39:16] sqlsrv_connect: SQLSTATE = 01000
[01-Apr-2011 12:39:16] sqlsrv_connect: error code = 5701
[01-Apr-2011 12:39:16] sqlsrv_connect: message = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'my_table_name'.
[01-Apr-2011 12:39:16] sqlsrv_connect: SQLSTATE = 01000
[01-Apr-2011 12:39:16] sqlsrv_connect: error code = 5703
[01-Apr-2011 12:39:16] sqlsrv_connect: message = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english.
[01-Apr-2011 12:39:16] error ignored
```

How can I suppress this error? It doesn't appear to be a PHP error as it doesn't have a severity such as Notice/Warning/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could use the [**`sqlsrv_configure()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644931%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function, to change the error reporting and/or logs settings.

See also :

- [Logging Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296188%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [Configure Error and Warning Handling Using the SQLSRV Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626306%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This did the trick: sqlsrv_configure( 'LogSubsystems', SQLSRV_LOG_SYSTEM_OFF ); (thanks!)